# How to convert a String to ArrayList?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I store an ArrayList in a file as a String ( arrayList.toString()).
How do i convert it back into an ArrayList?

Overall, I just want to convert something like: [Eve, Anna, Tony, Steve] back to an ArrayList. Any ideas?

Comment: What if someone puts their name in as Smith, John?

Comment: Please read about serialization: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Comment: read - split - convert array to list

Comment: What was the exact homework description? Can you post a copy of the paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All you need is a java.lang.String's split() & java.util.Arrays asList():**

```
    String fruits = "Orange,Apple,Grape";
    String[] array = fruits.split(",");
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);

    //Code to check the content in the List (for your understanding only)
    for(String s : list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

**Prints below output:**

```
    Orange
    Apple
    Grape
```

Comment: And the `[]` brackets?